# OpenVPN Permission Denied Error

Tags: vpn, openvpn, permissions

I am setting OpenVPN up, and I'm in the state of adding users.

**Details:**

- Host System: Windows Server 2003 32-bit.
- Guest System: Ubuntu Linux (with OpenVPN installed already), actually I downloaded it from [OpenVPN.Net](http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as/164.html).
- Virtualization: VMWare v7.0

**Problem:**
I can access the Access Server web portal (on the port 5480), but when I login to http://host_ip:943/admin and enter my (correct) login info, it shows me a page saying that "You don't have enough permissions". I am the (root) user!!!! that is really weird!!!

Note: if I enter wrong login it will denote an incorrect login, this means that I am logging in successfully but the problem comes after the login process.

**What I tried:**
I tried to create another user after (root) logging in to Linux Bash using (useradd) command, but the same resulted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user you use to login is not the root-user for the machine, but a user created while installing OpenVPN. The default user to log in is 'Openvpn'.

This is a fairly good tutorial on the subject: http://www.jack-brennan.com/?p=958

Comment: thanks (+1 for the login name), he says `login as jack with the same password...`, anyway, if the login is `Openvpn`, what is the default password? and please be sure of the case sensitivity of both the name and the password.

Comment: When you ran the initial wizard to configure it, it should have asked you. If not, no worries. Just run 'sudo /usr/local/openvpn_as/bin/ovpn-init' and first type DELETE. Then he will ask you once agin to provide him with a username/pasw. Let me know how it went ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. The link doesn't work though, but it seems the guy has moved it to a new area on the site. The article you are referring to above has a new URL. http://www.jack-brennan.com/?p=958 I hope that helps someone out because the tutorial is quite good.